# Keycloak container not able to connect to external database

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, keycloak

I am trying to connect keycloak docker image quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.2 to Azure managed postgres database instance.
Reason: Our main application db is on azure so it's preferrable for us to point keycloak to same database.

We already tried and tested the keycloak functionality using standalone linux installation (./bin/kc.sh) which easily connected to azure postgres database and all our realms and user, client configuration is set into this azure postgres database.

```
Command: docker run --env-file endpoint.txt -p 8080:8080 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.2 start-dev
```

Contents in endpoint.txt file:

```
DB_VENDOR=postgres
DB_ADDR=Azure_postgres_url
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=keycloak_database
DB_USER=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Behaviour:
http://public_ip:8080/

Keycloak landing page shows but it's not connected to existing azure db, we have to set admin account , realms and user configurations from scratch.
Mostly keycloak is using it's internal database (H2)

Your help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: have you tried opening a shell in the container and pinging the postgres host? If you can't install ping in this container use any other base image and run a container next to it.

Comment: The keycloak image I am using is official image available on Docker Hub, how I am supposed to use another base image for it?

Comment: :) use another image just to validate that you can ping the server from your docker daemon running on that host. If this other container cannot ping the server, then so doesn't you "keycloak official image" and that's your problem to fix

Comment: I was able to connect to the external database with keycloak container. However I am not able to access the admin console page. http://IP:8080   works, http://IP:8080/admin/master/console/ is stuck in white screen